# Minecraft lags when playing in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with AMD R4/R5 graphics

Tags: 64-bit, 18.04, minecraft

I installed the Minecraft launcher from software center and started playing but the video lags very much and the game becomes very slow. I have Radeon r4 graphics.

Details from System Settings:

```
     Ubuntu 18.04  
Device name abhishek-HP  
     Memory 3.3 GiB  
  Processor AMD® A6-6310 apu with radeon a4 graphics ✕ 4  
   Graphics llvm pipe (LLVM 6.0, 128 bits)  
      GNOME 3.28.1  
    OS type 64-bit  
       Disk 168.1 GB
```

These are some results of codes that I used following [this post](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2388311):

```
$ lspci | grep ati
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics]
$ lsmod | grep radeon
radeon               1470464  2
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 amdgpu,radeon
ttm                   106496  2 amdgpu,radeon
drm_kms_helper        167936  2 amdgpu,radeon
drm                   401408  6 amdgpu,radeon,ttm,drm_kms_helper
$ lsmod | grep amdgpu
amdgpu               2703360  0
chash                  16384  1 amdgpu
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 amdgpu,radeon
ttm                   106496  2 amdgpu,radeon
drm_kms_helper        167936  2 amdgpu,radeon
drm                   401408  6 amdgpu,radeon,ttm,drm_kms_helper
$ lspci | grep VGA
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics]
$ lspci -nn | grep '\[03'
00:01.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mullins [Radeon R4/R5 Graphics] [1002:9851]
```